# How to sent uploaded image details(name,size, temp_name,error) for upload using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am submiting form using JavaScript. Now I want to store/move image into folder using javaScript. 
HTML Code -

```
<form id="exampleForm" method="post" action=""  enctype="multipart/form-data" >

     <input  type="file" name="imagename" id="imagename" />
     <input type="button" name="save_exit"  id="save_exit" onclick="submitForm('add_question_sql.php')" value="Save &amp; Exit"  />

</form>
```

JavaSript Code-

```
function submitForm(action)
{
    document.getElementById('exampleForm').action = action;
    document.getElementById('exampleForm').submit();// submiting form
}
```

So how to sent image details (name, size, temp_name,error) to action page for move uploading process.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <form id="exampleForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
             <input  type="file" name="imagename" id="imagename" />
             <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Ajax:

```
$("form#exampleForm").submit(function(){

    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url:'add_question_sql.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

    return false;
});
```